# How can I change the default width of Finder columns?

Tags: macos, finder

I have found OS X's **default** column width to be a bit too narrow. Is there any way to make it wider?

I know how to resize columns manually, but it's annoying to repeat the process every time I open a new folder. Can I force Finder to "remember" the new column width? Also, if this is possible, can anyone point me toward the official Apple documentation that describes how to do it?

Comment: Join me in telling them you'd like this auto-column width size too here:
http://www.apple.com/feedback/
(under "OS X APPS" choose OS X for category to report in)....maybe if enough of us keep telling them, they will write some script to add to OS X!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In column view in the Finder, you can resize columns by positioning the mouse pointer over over the thin line that separates column panes, and dragging it to the left to make it narrower or to the right to make it wider.

To make the Finder remember the new width, [hold down the option key(<kbd>⌥</kbd>)](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=291437) while dragging the pane separator to the desired width.

The [best documentation I can find on this from Apple](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.7/en/mchlp1745.html) alludes to the fact that holding down option resizes "all columns at once" but does not explicitly say that this makes the change persistent.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I can't believe how non-obvious it is, though.

Comment: The option key! I keep pressing it in menus just to discover new and hidden features in MacOSX. It's as if I'm on a treasure hunt :)

Comment: @Chris if it's exactly what you're looking for, you can accept it as the correct answer so future people with the same problem can more easily find this answer.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, I just forgot to come back to this question (I hate accepting answers *too* quickly). I was also still kind of hoping that someone would provide a link to the official Apple documentation on this, as well. Apple must have documented it somewhere, right?

Comment: Adding the best Apple documentation I can find.

Comment: This does not work on OS X Lion. :(

Comment: @Noldorin The answer was written for Lion, and it works on my install of 10.7.4. What happens for you when you try it?

Comment: Nada. Zilch. Incidentally, the proper way to do this is to go to View > Show View Options > Use As Default.

Comment: FYI This broken in Mavericks as well. Holding down the option key changes all columns in the view but click on anything else in the folder and they snap back. In addition the View Options no longer has "Use As Default"

Comment: @DanielLawson do you know how to set the default window size for Finder?

Comment: This doesn't work on OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Still doesn't work on OS X El Capitan

Comment: Tested - still working on El Capitan 10.11.6 at July 2016.

Comment: This does not work in Sierra, in list mode, on the desktop.  Other folders seem to remember their last setting, but the desktop resets the moment I click away and return to it.  The only option is to have two finder windows, one that is always on desktop and the other for all others.  Not a good solution.  There's got to be a better way.

Comment: It seems hit or miss in Mojave that it will remember the column widths of folders. And this opt-drag certainly doesnt affect a default size for new folders. Nothing seems too from what I have tried. So much screaming at the finder to stop being forgetful.

Answer (score 3):

I am using El Capitan. I have found the following:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Left click on right hand border makes width and height change.
- <kbd>Option</kbd> and Left click on right hand border reduces horizontal width from the right maintaining column width.

At the bottom of the column borders are 2 small vertical lines. Placing the cursor on these will ...

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Left click changes column width of the left side column.
- <kbd>Option</kbd> + Left click changes column width of all columns to the same size.

Using <kbd>Command</kbd> instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd> seems to have the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

In MacOS Catalina, You can OPT-Drag the thick divider by dragging it from the bottom most part. You'll see an icon like  `||`. Use that to drag. Clicking anywhere else, doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, I could only get the thick dividers to appear by selecting **System Preferences > General > Show scroll bars > Always** on macOS Catalina, but your mileage may vary.